# C++11 alias and template template

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, alias

I have the following classes

```
struct Abis
{
  void foo() { // does something }
};

struct A
{
  typedef Abis bis_type; 
  bis_type create() { // instanciates Abis object };

};

template<class Tbis> // typically Tbis would be Abis
struct Bbis
{
  // something
};

template<class T> // typically T would be A
struct B
{
  typedef Bbis<typename T::bis_type> bis_type; 
  bis_type create() { // instanciates Bbis object };
};
```

Now I would like to add another layer :

```
template<class Tbis, template<class> class Ubis> 
struct Cbis : public Ubis<Tbis>
{
   void additional_method() { // does something calling Tbis and Ubis methods}
};
```

and have a class C instantiating a Cbis object so I can write something like that:

```
C<A,B> c();
Cbis<Abis,Bbis> cbis = c.create();
cbis.additional_method();
```

This requires being able to refer to the typedef bis_types so I tried this

```
template<class T, template<class> class U> 
struct C
{
   template<class S>
   using Ubis_type = U<S>::bis_type // PROBLEM!
   typedef Cbis<typename T::bis_type,Ubis_type> bis_type; 

   bis_type create(); 
}
```

This does not seem to work and neither does

```
template<class T, template<class> class U> 
struct C
{
   template<class S>
   using Ubis_type = typename U<S>::bis_type // PROBLEM!
   typedef Cbis<typename T::bis_type,Ubis_type> bis_type; 

   bis_type create(); 
}
```

As a temporary fix, I can pass a B type as a template parameter to Cbis but this does not really respect the design and I would like to understand what the problem is.

Is my syntax correct? (I am using XCode 7.3)

Thanks

Comment: You're already off to the wrong start, even before you got out of the gate: `typedef Bbis bis_type;` -- "Bbis" is not a type. It's a template. Big difference. Of course "U<S>" is "A PROBLEM!" There is no template U defined anywhere. All of this looks like fantasy code, not real code.

Comment: *"This does not seem to work and neither does"*, include the error messages

Comment: template<class T> // it doesn't make sense as you don't use T class at all...

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is with your `typedef Bbis bis_type` line - `Bbis` is a class template rather than a class. I think most likely what you mean there is `typedef Bbis<T> bis_type` (given that you have a type `T` in that context). After that, your code largely works (I had to correct a few typos to get it to compile), here is the final version:

(**UPDATE:** changed definition of `struct C` to fit with required use case of `C<A, B>`)

```
struct Abis
{
  void foo() { // does something 
  }
};

struct A
{
  typedef Abis bis_type; 
  bis_type create() { // instanciates Abis object 
    return Abis();
  }

};

template<class Tbis> // typically Tbis would be Abis
struct Bbis
{
  // something
};

template<class T> // typically T would be A
struct B
{
  typedef Bbis<T> bis_type; 
  bis_type create() { // instanciates Bbis object 
  };
};

template<class Tbis, template<class> class Ubis> 
struct Cbis : public Ubis<Tbis>
{
   void additional_method() { // does something calling Tbis and Ubis methods
   }
};

template<class T, template<class> class U> 
struct C
{
   template<class S>
   using Ubis_type = typename U<S>::bis_type; // PROBLEM!

   typedef Cbis<typename U<T>::bis_type,Ubis_type> bis_type; 

   bis_type create()
   {
        return bis_type();    
   } 
};
```

Then you could use your final `struct C` like this:

```
int main(int argc, char**args) 
{
    C<A, B> c;
    auto d = c.create();

    d.additional_method();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. I edited my post to correct the definition of B<T>::bis_type (this was correctly defined in my actual code so this is not the issue). I also gave an example of the end result I am aiming for.

Comment: See my edits above. You can now use `C<A, B>` as required. Note: your (manual) deduction of the return type of `C::create()` was wrong. However, you can just use `auto` and not worry about it. The final object `d` is perfectly usable and can have `additional_method` invoked on it as you can see in my answer

Comment: Ok so you are saying that my syntax is correct as long as I use typename for the dependant type ?

Comment: Not exactly - there was another subtle problem with the definition of `C` which I've corrected (compare my `C` closely to yours). The relevant change there is to `typedef ... bis_type`, in particular the first template parameter. You're using a template template there, so it needs a template parameter itself.